# nodejs: Does database connection cost matter?

Tags: node.js, database, performance, connection

1.synchronous

```
mongo.conn(function(err,db){
 db.collection('pet').find({},function(err, result){
    db.collection('petviewcount').updateOne({}, {$inc:{viewcount:+1}}, function(err, result){
        // db.collection('more').find({},function(err, result){
            // db.collection('insert').find({},function(err, result){
                // db.collection('update').find({},function(err, result){
                db.close();
                cb(err, result);
    });                    
});
```

});

2.asynchronous

```
mongo.conn(function(err,db){
    db.collection('pet').find({},function(err, result){
                db.close();
                cb(err, result);
    });
});
countUp();
// more + insert + update()

function countUp(){
  mongo.conn(function(err,db){
    db.collection('petviewcount').updateOne({}, {$inc:{viewcount:+1}}, function(err, result){
        db.close();
    });
  });
}
```

As far as I know when sending a single request to server(node) 
The first one is saving connection cost between server and database. 
The second one is a faster response than previous one. 
Which is better in the real world?  
( 1. Little data latency is acceptable 
    2. I don't know how to dealing with between server and database performance bottleneck. )

Comment: You misunderstand the concept of synchronous and asynchronous process. Both of your sample codes run in asynchronously. For performance wise, re-use connection is better than make a new one on each request because making connection requires resource and overhead.

Comment: If there were no callbacks in the above example, Is it synchronous? or is it synchronous when using sleep function or node-sync lib something? I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance wise, re-use connection is better than make a new one on each request because making connection requires resource and overhead.

I think his is a better approach:

```
//global connection reference
var dbConnection;

//remember to wait for connection established before using the connection
mongo.conn(function(err,db){
  dbConnection = db;
  start();  //now you can run all query with one connection
});

function start() {
  findPet();
  countUp();
}

function findPet() {
  dbConnection.collection('pet').find({},function(err, result){
  });
}

function countUp(){
  dbConnection.collection('petviewcount').updateOne({}, {$inc:{viewcount:+1}}, function(err, result){
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtfulness :)